# Unslider not functioning with responsive design

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, slider

I'm designing a site that my client wants to be non-responsive for tablets+ resolutions, and responsive for mobile devices.  I've been working on getting Unslider to work fluidly for the responsive design, but as soon as the screen is resized the Unslider gets really small/unreadable and wont go back to full-size when the screen is expanded.  When I change the "fluid" option to "false" is continues to act strangely, but without the gradual fluidity change.

Here's the site (it seemed pretty complex to fit into a fiddle, since it seems site-specific):
http://moore.whiterabbitstudio.us/

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This seemed to fix it: .banner {
 position: relative;
overflow: auto;
min-width:100%;
width: 100%;
max-width: 696px;
 }

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I am having the same problem. I still cannot figure out why you included `max-width:696px;`. Could you please explain?

Comment: It was just for my specific slider/design. I didn't want the slider getting any larger than 696px wide in large browser windows.